# how to query case insensitivity and contains with Spring MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate, spring-mongo

I have JSON documents in MongoDB like these

```
{
  "os" : "Windows 10"
}

{
  "os" : "WINDOWS 8"
}

{
  "os" : "UBunTu 18.04"
}
```

how can I query on `os` with case insensitivity and contains using Spring MongoTemplate so that I can  pass `["windows", "ubuntu"]`   and get all three documents from DB

I tried something like this but did not work.

```
String osRegEx = String.join(" | ", new String[]{"windows", "ubuntu"});
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("os").regex(osRegEx, "i"));
```

Answer (score 5):

It worked in this way...

```
String osRegEx = String.join("|", new String[]{"windows.*", "ubuntu.*"});
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("os").regex("("+osRegEx+")", "i"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this issue because of the string that you have provided for regex. You have `Windows 10` etc in mongo with the version number but you are only having the regex string to match the windows/ubuntu part :

```
String osRegEx = String.join(" | ", new String[]{"windows.*", "ubuntu.*"});
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("os").regex(osRegEx, "i"));
```

Comment: it is working with one ```"os" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "Ubuntu.*", "options" : "i"}}}``` but when I pass both ```"os" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "CentOS.* | Ubuntu.*", "options" : "i"}}}``` its not returning any results

Comment: throwing ```InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException```. it is not allowing multiple ```'os'``` in ```$or```

Comment: Yes sorry it won't work , I think the regex should have a grouping like : `(windows.*|ubuntu.*)`

Comment: Wow.. it worked when I used ```(windows.*|ubuntu.*)```

Comment: ```String osRegEx = String.join("|", new String[]{"windows.*", "ubuntu.*"});
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("os").regex("("+osRegEx+")", "i"));```

Comment: @MAHIE it was the issue with the regex afterall !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
String [] queryStrs = { "windows", "ubuntu" };
String patternStr = Stream.of(queryStrs).collect(Collectors.joining("|", "(", ")"));
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria().regex(pattern);
Query query = Query.query(criteria);
List<Foo> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, Foo.class);
```

Comment: I do not understand why someone has **down voted** the answer. The code works fine - it returns the required result. One can request for an explanation of the APIs / code used in the post.